# Is there an English term for a function which is locally linearizable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, terminology

In Italian we have the notion of *derivabilità* and *differenziabilità*. In one dimension they are equivalent; in more dimensions, instead:

- A function is *derivabile* if partial derivatives exist.
- A function is *differenziabile* if it is also *localmente linearizzabile* (locally linearizable), that is, if
  $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)-\partial_xf(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)-\partial_yf(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)}{\sqrt[]{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}}=0$$

Is there an English term which translates *differenziabile*, other than locally linearizable?

Comment: I believe we usually call the second property differentiability instead

Comment: So you use differentiability for both?

Comment: The first property doesn't have a special name as far as I am aware

Comment: Ok, I understand

Comment: We have (Fréchet) differentiability (your second property) and Gâteaux differentiability (all directional derivative exists, not just partials derivatives) in English.  There are others too, e.g. Hadamard differentiability (which only distinguish itself in infinite dimensional setting).